# How to I set the Content Type of a Google Cloud Function HTTP response

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do I set the `Content-Type` of a response from a HTTP Google Cloud Function in Python? Right now I have something like:

```
def my_function(request):
    xml = ...
    return xml
```

This correctly returns my XML, but the `Content-Type` is wrong (it's `text/html` instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions uses [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) under the hood, so you can return a [`flask.Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response) object instead of a string to produce a custom response.

In your `requirements.txt` file, add `flask`:

```
flask==1.0.2
```

In your function:

```
from flask import Response

def my_function(request):
    xml = ...
    return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, as shown in the Cloud Functions docs under [Authentication and CORS](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors_auth-python):

```
def my_function(request):
    xml = ...

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

    return (xml, 200, headers)
```

Comment: This is really the better answer, since it solves the problem within the framework without introducing addition ones.